# PHP - reload first page from anywhere on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the below javascript function which displays updated values after a UI slider selection on the click of a button. I have disabled the button across pages so that the button will not be clicked again.

```
 $(function () {
            var disabled = localStorage.getItem("updateDisabled");
            if (disabled) $('#update').attr('disabled', disabled);
            });


             $("#update").click(function (){
             this.disabled = true;
             localStorage.setItem("updateDisabled", true);
            $("#kwBody > tr").each(function() {
               var $cells = $(this).children("td");

               var found=false,count=0,currentCell;
               for (var i=0;i<masterData.length;i++) {
                 currentCell=$cells.eq(i+1);
                 found = parseInt(currentCell.text(),10) >=masterData[i];
                 currentCell.toggleClass("found",found); //add or remove class to highlight 
                 count+=found;
               }
               window.console && console.log(masterData,count);
               $(this).toggle(count==masterData.length); // show if all cells >

            });
```

In my page, I am trying to include another button like "Back" which when clicked on, will reload the initial page itself.

```
   <form method="post" action"willdoit.php">
<input type = "button" value = "Back"></input>
</form>
```

However if I click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: where did you handle back button click?

Comment: change the `type = "button"` to `type = "submit"`

Comment: I want to reload the same "willdoit.php" page as it gets displayed initially. However, if I click on the back button nothing happens.

Comment: In your form declaration you're missing an `=` between action and the URL:` <form method="post" action="willdoit.php">`

Comment: I am displaying the values in a paginated format. If I click on back from the second page, the form gets reset in the second page itself. However, I need it to be reset in the first page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type ="submit" value ="Back" />
```

This will submit your form. Your button you have will only be a button and do nothing.

Comment: I am displaying the values in a paginated format. If I click on back from the second page, the form gets reset in the second page itself. However, I need it to be reset in the first page. Is it possible?

Comment: You will need to pass in your page variable and handle the redirect back to that page with your PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

Change the type to input type ="submit"